# How Do You Animate Vine Tiles (Like in Terraria) Using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Would you use GameObjects or Unity's tilemap? If they're tiles, how do you make them interactable/physics based?

I've tried using GameObjects with a Sprite and 2D Collider, and a shader animates the wind/player interaction.

But the worst-case scenario is a player could place thousands of vine objects into the game (even with chunk loading and pool managers, it's costly).

It's also an issue if I have hundreds of other object types in the pool manager that require custom animations/Fx/scripts (chest opening, camp fire, torch, etc.).

Whilst GameObjects provide more flexibility and allow me to attach additional components, scripts, and behaviors to individual objects, it's a lot more costly.